# Making the database.yml file work in Rails on OSX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rake

I understand that using postgres on osx is a little difficult because it has its own version running, and so in order to psql to it you need to supply the host name like so

psql -h localhost mydatabasename -U me

However how do you do this for your database.yml file for all the rail loveliness.

If you try to connect with

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  username: me
  database: mydatabasename
```

you receive the classic

```
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "username"=>"me", "database"=>"mydatabasename"}
could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Any ideas on how to supply the information or config osx not to suck so much?!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you're able to connect to Postgres on localhost with `psql`, then just add:

```
 host: localhost
```

to the `database.yml`

Answer (score 5):

My working configuration is as follows:

```
development:
    adapter: postgresql
    database: database_name
    host: localhost
    username: user_name
    pool: 5
    timeout: 5000
```

So I suppose you need to add host: localhost.

Answer (score 0):

```
 development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: name
  username: hading
  password: my_db_password
  host: localhost # not mandatory
  pool: 5 # not mandatory
  timeout: 5000 # not mandatory
```