# Ruby 1.9.3-p392 and PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, pg

I created a new rails app with `rails new app_name -d postgresql` and I am failing to use any rails command (`rails s`, `rails g controller ControllerName`, etc etc). I am getting these errors:

``` /Users/sebkomianos/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1216:in ``initialize': could not connect to server: No such file or directory (PG::Error) ```

This is my `database.yml` file:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: project_development
  pool: 5
  username: project
  password:`

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: project_test
  pool: 5
  username: project
  password:`

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: project_production
  pool: 5
  username: project
  password:`
```

I am having the exact same problem when I create the rails app with the standard `rails new app_name` command and manually change the `Gemfile` to use the `pg gem`.

A couple of weeks ago I was on ruby2 and the app I created was working fine. Rails version is 3.2.13.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:** The funny (at least to me) thing is that I have the application deployed to heroku and it runs fine there. Now, if I run `rake db:create` everything seems to be working fine locally as well (no need to change anything in the `database.yml` file). Maybe that makes my problem more clear?

Comment: Did you run `bundle install`?

Comment: Did you remember to change directories into your project directory?

Comment: @aceofbassgreg Can you elaborate on this please?

Comment: Is your Postgres server running?

Comment: Try adding `host: localhost` as suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/a/9851547/429758

Comment: @PrakashMurthy I tried - although it's not the optimal solution as I have a collaborator on this project - but it didn't help.

Comment: @sebkomianos - one error that sometimes happens is, a rails user is in, let's say a `projects` directory and then enters the command `rails new project1`. Then they forget to `cd` into the `projects1` directory and are then unsuccessful in their attempts to use Rails commands. It sounds like this wasn't your problem, but I did want to answer your question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to specify the `socket` argument in your `config/database.yml` to specify the full path to the Postgres UNIX-type socket if that's what you're using. It may be in a non-standard location.

I usually avoid checking `config/database.yml` into the project source repository as it causes conflicts with other people working on the same code-base that have different configurations. Include a `database.yml.example` as a helpful template to get started instead.

Adding `host: localhost` usually has the effect of forcing a TCP/IP connection instead, but this might not be working for you. Sometimes `host: 127.0.0.1` works instead, as `localhost` might be interpreted as "use default UNIX socket".

Comment: Okay, so adding `host: 127.0.0.1` fixed it. But from what I understand it's not a standard/suggest solution. Given that I have very minimal knowledge about database administration/configuration, how can I find the socket/how do I fix the location? **(I updated the question with a new find)**

Comment: Heroku probably has their Postgres socket in the default location. If you're using an installer like Homebrew or MacPorts it might create it in a place the Ruby adapter does not know to look. The most reliable solution here is to find your Postgres socket, if you have one, and set that as the `socket` parameter. It may be that your server is not configured to create one for whatever reason.